# Crashes when compiled using Multi-threaded (/MT)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, crash, leveldb

I am new to leveldb. I tried to compile my c++ code for creating a leveldb in Visual Studio 2015. I tried to compile the code with two different Code Generation option.

To change the property:
Project->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation

This is my entire code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "leveldb/db.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    leveldb::DB* db;
    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    //options.error_if_exists = true;
    /*This is the line where it crashes*/
    leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "E:\\testdb\\level2", &db);
    /*This is the line where it crashes*/
    if (!status.ok()) 
    {
        cerr << status.ToString() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Created successfully" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        status = db->Put(leveldb::WriteOptions(), to_string(i), to_string(i));
    }
    delete db;
    return 0;
}
```

The below are the results of my two case

**Case:1**

Runtime Library->Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

**Result:**

The Code Compiled successfully and i could see successfull execution of my code and the db is created

**Case:2**

Runtime Library->Multi-threaded (/MT)

**Result:**

The Code Compiled successfully. But the exe gets crashes whenever it tries to open the database

The below is the line where my exe is getting crashed

**leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "E:\\testdb\\level2", &db);**

Comment: Since when does leveldb work on Windows? The github page also seems rather clear on that, there's even an issue: https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/363

Comment: But the code, when compiled in MD it works for me. It creates the database with one million entries. I need some suggestion regarding any open source key value DBs, consider using it in a commercial purpose.

Comment: Check out [this port to windows](https://github.com/ren85/leveldb-windows). Been using it for a long time - no problems.